# How is memory allocated for a static variable?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

In the below program:

```
class Main
{   
    static string staticVariable = "Static Variable";
    string instanceVariable = "Instance Variable";

    public Main(){}   
}
```

The `instanceVariable` will be stored inside the memory allocated for object instance. Where will the `staticVariable` be stored, is it stored in the object instance itself or somewhere else? If its stored somewhere else, how are the memory locations connected?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Memory for static variables are normally held in some rooted (and hidden) `object[]`. This can be seen doing a !gcroot on the object in WinDbg (with SOS).

Just to add, these references can never be GC'ed (unless you null the field), as I discovered recently.

Comment: Is it true that making static variable to null makes it's GC'ed. I'm really confused.

Answer (score -1):

For instance in C++ staic variables are allocated in global memory space with global variables. Compiler uses special naming convention to know that this variable belongs to the class.

Comment: This is a C# question