# Why is it possible to change the value of a readonly field but not of a const using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

Why is it possible to modify the value of a `readonly` field using reflection but not the value of a `const`?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foobar foobar = new Foobar();
        Console.WriteLine(foobar.foo);                   // Outputs "Hello"
        Console.WriteLine(Foobar.bar);                   // Outputs "Hello"

        var field = foobar.GetType().GetField("foo");
        field.SetValue(foobar, "World");                // Ok
        field = foobar.GetType().GetField("bar");
        field.SetValue(foobar, "World");                // Throws FieldAccessException

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Foobar
{
    public readonly string foo = "Hello";
    public const string bar = "Hello";
}
```

I've read [this answer](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/6722620/1011036) so I understand it's allowed to break the rules for `readonly` but why not for `const` in that case? I'm sure there's a good reason but I can't figure out what it could be.

-- Edit --

When I take a look at the code above using ildasm, the value of the `readonly` field is set at compile time. Not on the field itself unlike for the `const` but in the constructor of the class. So I'm not sure to get why one can be "overwritten" but not the other one.

What I mean is, even if the value of the `const` is "hard-coded" in the binary, is the reason for not being able to modifiy it a technical limitation in the framework itself because "it's already set" or just a design decision. I don't see any reason why there could not be some "magic" somewhere modifying the `const` as it's doing it for the `readonly`.

-- Edit 2 --

To add up to the accepted answer, there is also [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9109643/1011036) which is quite interesting. What I didn't get in the first place when asking this question is that the value behind the `const` is *really* replaced anywhere it is used in the code. With this declaration:

```
public const string Foo = "Hello";
```

writing later

```
Console.WriteLine(Foo);
```

is equivalent to writing

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
```

Indeed my code

```
Console.WriteLine(foobar.foo);
Console.WriteLine(Foobar.bar);
```

is replaced in IL by

```
IL_0008:  ldfld      string ConsoleApplication3.Foobar::foo
IL_000d:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_0012:  nop
IL_0013:  ldstr      "Hello"
IL_0018:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

Comment: See also: [What is the difference between const and readonly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-readonly)

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for your link. I didn't know about the way the memory was handled for `const` and the impact it could have on other assemblies. Modifying the value of a `const` could have unknown impact on other assemblies I guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `const` fields are 'set' at compile time, i.e. the compiler replaces the `const` with the given value during compilation. As a result of the way `const` values work, their values are copied into every assembly that uses them. Whereas `readonly` fields are evaluated at runtime.

Comment: When I take a look at the code in my question in ildasm, the value of the `readonly` field is also set at compile time. Not on the field itself, unlike for the `const` but in the constructor anyway. So I'm still not sure to get why one can be "overwritten" but not the other one.

Comment: @Guillaume can you please update your question to include your IL observations for both const and readonly.

Comment: @Guillaume what you might be observing is a compiler optimisation in this case that makes your readonly appear the same as your const declaration. You can't infer too much from the compiled code!

Answer (score 2):

Reason is that the constants are replaced with it value during the compile time itself. But readonly fields are not. You can set a value for a readonly fields either at declaraiotn and/or at that class's constructor. I Hope this answers your question.