# Using a list from another method in a static class

Tags: c#, list, nullreferenceexception

So I have a static class with a list declared as one of it's members, and I populate the list in a function lets say it's called PopulateList(). Is it possible to modify the list in another function without:

1) Calling it as a parameter
2) Instantiating it in a constructer (Trying to keep the class static. I'm working off of a template so I can't really change the structure of the classes)

Without somehow instantiating though, I will obviously receive null exceptions, so I was wondering if there is a 3rd way to do this.

```
       public Static class MyClass{

             static public List<String> m_SuiteFileNameList2=null;


        public static bool Function1(inp){
              //m_SuiteFileNameList2 stuff
         }

        public static void Function2(){
             //m_SuiteFileNameList2 other stuff
          }
       }
```

Comment: Code would be a little better than only words, please could you add a bit code?

Comment: Please show some code. It's unclear why you can't initialize the member directly.

Comment: why not just check if the list is instantiated when running your function, then instantiate it if it isn't already?

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a [static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), or static initialization.  It will allow you to keep your class `static`, but will ensure that the list is always defined:

```
static class MyClass
{
    static MyClass()
    {
        MyList = new List<Whatever>();
    }

    // etc
}
```

or

```
static class MyClass
{
    public static List<Whatever> MyList = new List<Whatever>();
}
```

Another option is to add a `null` check to every usage of the list:

```
public static void MyMethod()
{
    if (MyList == null)
    {
        MyList = new List<Whatever>();
    }
    //etc
}
```

Comment: I'm still having some trouble with the Static Constructor. It says the list is a field but is used like a type. Also I get an invalid '{' in class struct or interface

Comment: @user1819301 I missed some parentheses from the first example.

Comment: Thanks RoadieRich. That's the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would call a function called 'Initialize' which is static and takes care of your static members.

Though I would recommend against static members if possible.

Why?

- They can lead to head aches (yes, that hurts)
- Their behaviour in memory allocation is different ([How is memory allocated for a static variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337019/hows-memory-allocated-for-a-static-variable))

**code snippet**

```
public static class YourClass
{
    public static List<string> YourList;

    public static void InitializeList()
    {
        YourList = new List<string>();
        YourList.Add("hello");
        YourList.Add("how");
        YourList.Add("are");
        YourList.Add("you?");
    }
}
```

Call your Initialize-Function from outside:

```
 YourClass.InitializeList();
```

**EDIT:** Given your code , you can also do it this way:

```
  public Static class MyClass{

             static public List<String> m_SuiteFileNameList2=null;


        public static bool Function1(inp){
             if(m_SuiteFileNameList2 == null)
             { m_SuiteFileNameList2 = new List<String>();}
              //m_SuiteFileNameList2 stuff
         }

        public static void Function2(){
             if(m_SuiteFileNameList2 == null)
             { m_SuiteFileNameList2 = new List<String>();}
             //m_SuiteFileNameList2 other stuff
          }
       }
```

Comment: I disagree with point 2 `They use memory even though you don't use the class (they live as long the project lives)` This is false unless you Use it atleast `Once`