# Memory layout of static and readonly members

Tags: c#, memory-management

In .Net does const and static readonly are part of the containing class in regard the memory allocations? are they allocated per instance (even when they belong to the type itself)?

edit:
how this works with Serializion and sizeof operation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How's memory allocated for a static variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337019/hows-memory-allocated-for-a-static-variable)

Answer (score 4):

Memory for `static` fields, constant or not, is never allocated per instance. Moreover, `static const` [is not allowed](http://ideone.com/OrjjXw) - `const` is automatically considered one-per-class.

There are [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/755693/335858) between `const` and `static readonly` fields, but neither one of them changes the footprint of instances of the corresponding class.

Answer (score 2):

Memory for `static` members are allocated once when the type is loaded since it belongs to the type itself.

As for `const` it won't consume memory, they don't exist at all in runtime, they are burnt into IL. In other words they are hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

`static` members of a class belong to the `Type`, not the instance. The `Type` itself is loaded in the `Loader Heaps`, specifically inside the `HighFrequencyHeap`  once the type gets loaded. So to your question: No, they are not allocated per instance of the `Class`.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are stored in the loader heap, where the type information is stored as types are loaded.
This means that the storage for static variables will not be allocated until their type is loaded.